# Is it OK to call HTTP endpoints in an Angular service constructor?

Tags: angular

In the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#call-it-in-ngoninit), there is the following tip about code in a component constructor (second paragraph emphasized by me):

> #### Call it in `ngOnInit`
>
> While you could call `getHeroes()` in the constructor, that's not the best practice.
>
> **Reserve the constructor for simple initialization such as wiring
>   constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do
>   anything. It certainly shouldn't call a function that makes HTTP
>   requests to a remote server as a real data service would.**
>
> Instead, call `getHeroes()` inside the [`ngOnInit` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and let
>   Angular call `ngOnInit` at an appropriate time *after* constructing a
>   HeroesComponent instance.

What about for services? Is it also bad to have an HTTP call (just the launch of an async request where the `Observable` is stored locally) in the constructor? Services don't have an `ngOnInit()` event, so what would the best practice for **Services** be?

Answer (score 4):

I bet that you can find some examples of where constructor can be used with no harm but as a rule of thumb and best practice use "angular constructor" for it aka `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

Sometimes using constructor can be impossible or requires additional work. For example, you need to fetch data from backend using service because if `@Input()` data. Inputs are not bound during javascript object construction, but they are available in `ngOnInit`

Moreover what if you want to unit test your component/service? You create new instance for every test (thus invoking a constructor) and you are making additional calls to mocked http backend, or even worst - to live one.

Comment: I understand that for a **Component** you want to use `ngOnInit` instead of the constructor. Services don't have `@Input` parameters or lifecycle hooks (that I know of). What would the best practice be for **Services**?

Comment: @DanielGray Services are always used by someone. You inject them in a component or in Effects (when you use Redux/NGRX for app-state management)

Comment: @Antoniossss You have done a good job of explaining this. However, I think the question would have been more clear if an example was given. In my case, I have cart service. I store my cart items in the DB so I am making an API call to retrieve cart items. So in my service, I have a variable for `items: Array<CartItem> = []`. I would like to make an http call and call `setItems()` methods in the constructor to fetch and set the items. Is this preferred?

Comment: @theTypan I consider your usecase simple enough to hand over the Observable to the actual using Component and use async-Pipe in there which then deals all further handling regarding closing etc.